# recovery of sqldeveloper db connections from crashed system to new system

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My laptop motherboard crashed recently, I got replacement.
Now i want to copy sqldeveloper connections from my crashed laptop to new one
Is there anyway, can I get all my oracle db connections in new laptop.

Comment: You will need access to the files stored on hard disk in your old laptop. Do you have a solution for accessing that data? (It’s not obvious, if the motherboard in the old laptop is dead.) If you don’t have a solution, you will need one - and that is not an Oracle or a SQL Developer question. If you do have a solution, you can follow the suggestions in Jeff Smith’s answer.

Comment: Yes, I can access the hard disk of my crashed laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look for a connections.xml or a connections.json file.

Copy that over, you'll get everything but the passwords.

If you can manage to run the GUI on that old system, start it up, and use the Export Connections dialog - we'll let your encrypt/protect your connection passwords, and then import them on your new machine.

You'll find this file in you $HOME/.sqldeveloper folder on a Mac or Linux or in APPDATA/$USER/Roaming Profiles on Windows.

Comment: I don’t quite understand how one can run the GUI (or anything for that matter) on a machine with a fried motherboard. That seems like somewhat of a problem... and if there is a solution, it will have nothing to do with SQL Developer or Oracle.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I couldnt able to find connections.xml or connections.json in my backup(crashed laptop hdd)

Comment: you get a new motherboard? where exactly were you looking for those files? and what version of SQL Developer were you running?

Comment: I got new system, sqldeveloper folder and 3.2 version

Comment: 3.x is like 10 years old...but it should still have a connections.xml file

Comment: Got the file, connections.xml, to where i need to copy?

Comment: basically the same place you found it - just on your new machine

Comment: Done, all the connections loaded, but couldn't able to connect. it is giving below error while connecting.
IO Error: The network adapter could not establish the connection
Vendor code 17002

Comment: Can you ping the server? Make sure the port # is right as well